# What are the differences between exec and name in ros2 launch file?

Tags: launch, robotics, ros2

I'am a ros2 noob and I would like to understand differences between exec and name in launch file.

I'll give an example to be precise:

```
<launch>
    <node pkg="camera" exec="" name="">
</launch>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- exec: The filename of the executable
- name: The name that `ros2 node list` shows

For example, from the [tutorial comparison in launch files](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/How-To-Guides/Launch-file-different-formats.html):

There is a line that sets both `name` and `exec`

```xml
<node pkg="turtlesim" exec="turtlesim_node" name="sim" namespace="turtlesim2">
```

When I created a package to run that, here's what happens.

```bash
$ ros2 node list
/listener
/mimic
/my/chatter/ns/listener
/my/chatter/ns/talker
/talker
/turtlesim1/sim
/turtlesim2/sim
```

You can see how the node name shows up, with an extra caveat - because namespace was also added, it appears as `<namespace>/<name>`.

Now, for the executable, you can just go see that in your ROS installation directory. For example, on my Linux computer running `humble`, there's the executable. I added `-l` to show it's executable.

```
$ ls -l /opt/ros/humble/lib/turtlesim/turtlesim_node 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 798384 Jan 17 18:00 /opt/ros/humble/lib/turtlesim/turtlesim_node
```

An easy way to find out the executables in your package is through tab complete with `ros2 pkg executables <package_name>`

```
$ ros2 pkg executables turtlesim
turtlesim draw_square
turtlesim mimic
turtlesim turtle_teleop_key
turtlesim turtlesim_node
```

The reason you have both is because you may re-use the same executable multiple times in a DDS domain, so the `name` , or `namespace`, can be used to differentiate them.